# Where to put copy image code in my code?

Tags: php, html, ajax, database

i am using this code:

```
copy('imgurl', 'images/covers/file.jpeg');
```

To copy an image url to a file on my website.

This work when i have just the above code in a php page by itself but i cant get it to work when i put it into my actual code.

So here is what i am using:

```
try {

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs (blogtitle, blogdesc, coverimage, userID, frontpage, tags) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

if ($statement->execute(array($_POST['addbuildtitle'], $_POST['addbuilddesc'], $_POST['addbuildcover'], $_POST['adduserid'], $frontpage,    $_POST['addtags'])));
    $dbSuccess = true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $return['databaseException'] = $e->getMessage();
}

$return['databaseSuccess'] = $dbSuccess;
$return['lastid'] = $db->lastInsertId();

copy('imgurl', 'images/covers/file1.jpeg');

echo json_encode($return);
```

}

However this doesnt work and no image is created.

Where should it be placed? the imgurl will be replaced with a proper user input url, and also the file name will be created somehow once this works.

I also know its not secure but its not currently live and will be going through that soon :)

Comment: Do you get any error? Try `copy('imgurl', getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT') . '/images/covers/file1.jpeg');` and check the destination folder for permissions, it has to be writeable by the web server user.

Comment: no errors, the code itself works fine. But just not when its put into the code im using for inputting into the database

Comment: However I don't think `copy()` accepts a URL as a source parameter.

Comment: e.g.

copy('http://media.fastcar.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Stanced-Mazda-MX5-Miata-10.jpg', 'images/covers/file5.jpeg');

that works fine.

Comment: `$db->lastInsertId()` can't be outside the `try` block because `$db` could be undefined. If the PDO constructor throws an exception (database connection fails), your code will break at that point.

Comment: $db->lastInsertId() that works fine.

Everything works fine but the copy code just doesnt work in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define your $return variable
$return = array();
if ($statement->execute(array($_POST['addbuildtitle'], $_POST['addbuilddesc'],     $_POST['addbuildcover'], $_POST['adduserid'], $frontpage,    $_POST['addtags']))) // No trailing semicolon for an inline if statement
     $dbSuccess = true;
```

You could try this and see if it fixes your problem

Comment: Are you getting any errors?? and add an `if(copy(... , ...)){ echo 'something'; }else{ echo 'nothing happened'; ) }